# Does my file upload form work in PWA, and if not, how can I implement it?

Tags: php, file-upload, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to develop a PWA, and one of the main features is to be able to upload files to my server. Below is the code I am using which does work in a laptop setting (i.e. opening in Chrome on a laptop):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="fullscreen">
<div class="container">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/test/";
    $path = $path . basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        return;
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```

The above code, however, when I use it on my phone as the PWA, does not load at all. It gives me the option to upload, and I am able to select files, but once I press submit, the page just begins to load, but never completes loading/uploading the file to my server.

I am assuming it is an issue with using PHP code in the PWA,because the HTML works just fine on the PWA. I've tried looking for file upload solutions in Javascript, but they still use a bit of PHP.

If you want to test out the file upload form on my site in action, click [Here](http://lexapp.dx.am/blip/upload.php). Click the next link for the root page to install the PWA on mobile to test [Here](http://lexapp.dx.am/blip).

To sum up, I need to make a file upload form work on the PWA. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Neither of the links you included are PWAs but just regular web pages?

Comment: If you were to look at the second link, after a few seconds in the top right of the search bar, it says Install. If you were to access the second link on Mobile, and added the page to your app home screen, it opens as a PWA. I would assume that a PWA are basically web pages made into an app

Comment: The lighthouse test says it is not. And it could never be until it is hosted on an HTTPS server. If you run the Lighthouse test it will tell you exactly what you need to fix to make it a PWA.

Comment: Yes, I know I have been trying to get SSL on the site. And so maybe that is my issue: I think I need SSL for the site to work properly. I will check however. Thanks